# Xamarin.Forms Previewer not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin studio(v6.1) installed on my windows machine and I can not see the preview button for the xaml.

I have followed the steps as outlined [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/). Is there anything else I should do to get it working ?

Comment: Something seems off here. Xamarin Studio isn't supported on Windows anymore. So how can you have installed the newest version on your Windows machine?

Comment: I found a link on the xamarin blog somewhere, can not remember exactly where. Will try and look